# SMTP Error (250): Authentication failed through roundcubemail

Tags: macos, email, authentication, smtp, roundcube

I am pretty new on setting up webservices and i only have basic knowledge on networks, and i am trying to set one web service on a local server, to receive and send mail through an mail server hosted in my ISP.

Setup:
- OSX
- Roundcubemail
- Server app
- Dinamic IP with No-IP link

Here is my default.inc.php:

```
// ----------------------------------
// SMTP
// ----------------------------------

// SMTP server host (for sending mails).
// To use SSL/TLS connection, enter hostname with prefix ssl:// or tls://
// If left blank, the PHP mail() function is used
// Supported replacement variables:
// %h - user's IMAP hostname
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %z - IMAP domain (IMAP hostname without the first part)
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld

$config['smtp_server'] = ‘%n’;
// $config['smtp_server'] = ‘’;

// SMTP port (default is 25; use 587 for STARTTLS or 465 for the
// deprecated SSL over SMTP (aka SMTPS))

$config['smtp_port'] = 25;

// SMTP username (if required) if you use %u as the username Roundcube
// will use the current username for login

$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
// $config['smtp_user'] = '';

// SMTP password (if required) if you use %p as the password Roundcube
// will use the current user's password for login

$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
// $config['smtp_pass'] = '';

// SMTP AUTH type (DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN or empty to use
// best server supported one)

$config['smtp_auth_type'] = ‘LOGIN’;
// $config['smtp_auth_type'] = ‘’;

// Optional SMTP authentication identifier to be used as authorization proxy
$config['smtp_auth_cid'] = null;

// Optional SMTP authentication password to be used for smtp_auth_cid
$config['smtp_auth_pw'] = null;

// SMTP HELO host 
// Hostname to give to the remote server for SMTP 'HELO' or 'EHLO' messages 
// Leave this blank and you will get the server variable 'server_name' or 
// localhost if that isn't defined.
$config['smtp_helo_host'] = '';

// SMTP connection timeout, in seconds. Default: 0 (use default_socket_timeout)
// Note: There's a known issue where using ssl connection with
// timeout > 0 causes connection errors ([url]https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54511[/url])
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 0;

// SMTP socket context options
// See [url]http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php[/url]
// The example below enables server certificate validation, and
// requires 'smtp_timeout' to be non zero.
// $config['smtp_conn_options'] = array(
//   'ssl'         => array(
//     'verify_peer'  => true,
//     'verify_depth' => 3,
//     'cafile'       => '/etc/openssl/certs/ca.crt',
//   ),
// );
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = null;
```

And i am getting a:

```
SMTP Error (250): Authentication failed.
```

Without being possible to send mails to no one.

And If i change those to default:

```
$config['smtp_server'] = ‘’;
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['smtp_user'] = '';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '';
$config['smtp_auth_type'] = ‘’;
```

I would have a different output, here i am able to send and receive mails between my several domains in my ISP, but i am unable to send mails to domains such as gmail.com, receiving the following error:

```
SMTP Error (550): Failed to add recipient "XXX" (Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.
XXX (XXX.local) [XXX]:XXX
is not permitted to relay through this server without authentication.).
```

I have also activated the smtp log, but cannot see where is the problem:

```
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 220-cpanel.X.pt ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 17 Oct 2016 11:16:24 +0100 
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Send: EHLO X.local
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250-cpanel.X.pt Hello X.pt [X]
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250-SIZE 52428800
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250-8BITMIME
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250-PIPELINING
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250-STARTTLS
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250 HELP
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Send: RSET
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 250 Reset OK
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Send: QUIT
[17-Oct-2016 11:16:24 +0100]: <sbg56vpg> Recv: 221 cpanel.X.pt closing connection
```

I discover that SMTP works with authentication through SPF and DKIM but dont know if that is interfering with SMTP auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FINALLY found what was doing this, it was my server app, i had to leave Mail turned on but without any relay outgoing mail through ISP activated, and i could not leave Mail turned off. :D